# SessionAttributes cause problems with multiple tabs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I have a Spring web app (Spring 3.2) and I have used following scenario to handle edit pages:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "packet" })
public class PacketController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-packet/{packet_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editPacketForm(@PathVariable(value = "packet_id") Long packet_id, Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("packet", packetService.findById(packet_id));
    return "packets/packetEdit";
}
```

POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-packet/{packet_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String packetEditAction(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "packet") 
                                   Packet packet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
    {
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
        return "packets/packetEdit";
    }

    packetService.update(packet);
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Now the problem is what if someone tries to open multiple tabs for /edit-packet/{id} with different ids. With every new open tab the session 'packet' object will be overwritten. Then after trying to submit forms on multiple tabs, first tab will be submitted but it actually change the second packet because in session is second object and second tab will cause error because setComplete has been invoked so there is no 'packet' object in session.

(This is known issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4160).

I am trying to implement this solution http://duckranger.com/2012/11/add-conversation-support-to-spring-mvc/ to solve this problem. I copied ConversationalSessionAttributeStore.java
ConversationIdRequestProcessor.java classes and in my servlet-config.xml I made this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="conversationalSessionAttributeStore"
    class="com.xx.session.ConversationalSessionAttributeStore">
</bean>

<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="com.xx.session.ConversationIdRequestProcessor" />
```

But it doesn't work, in my POST methods I don't see any new parameters, did I miss something?

**UPDATE**: Actually, it started working, but maybe someone has a better idea to solve this issue?

My other idea is to force a new session on every new tab, but it's not a nice solution.

Comment: Don't store the ting in the session,. make it stateless. When updating pass the id and the data needed for changing, reload and update. Works with 1 or 100 tabs that way.

Comment: @ M. Deinum Yea now i think you are right even though it requires more code. But i saw my approach in multiple tutorials, its even in Spring pet clinic project which i thought contains best practices so i used it but now i see it has huge problems.

Comment: It isn't about best practices it is a showcase on how to work with certain technologies... Please don't confuse the 2.

Comment: Also it doesn't require much additional code. Just add a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` which loads the selected `Packet` from the database. The method will automatically be called before each request handling method. You could then cleanup your GET method and your POST method would still work as intended.

Comment: How can i pass id to @ModelAttribute so it loads right object from database? I've never seen example like that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use session attributes, make your controller stateless and simply use the path variable to retrieve the correct model attribute.

```
@Controller
public class PacketController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public Packet packet(@PathVariable(value = "packet_id") Long packet_id) {
        return packetService.findById(packet_id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit-packet/{packet_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPacketForm() {
        return "packets/packetEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit-packet/{packet_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String packetEditAction(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "packet") 
                                   Packet packet, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "packets/packetEdit";
        }

        packetService.update(packet);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: It will not work if i have any other method in that controller without packet_id in url. In that controller i have also addPacket, and displayPackets methods. I think it can work as expected with converters like this: @PathVariable(value = "packet_id") Packet packet, and if packet is null then create new one but i am not sure if its the right way to handle this.

Comment: If you are using Spring Data JPA that behavior is added for you out-of-the-box :). Also when posting/putting with an ID the entity should already exists. You could also create 2 controllers separating the known (with path variable) and unknown (without path variable) controllers.

Comment: I dont use Spring Data JPA, but i have some custom converters. Anyway it seems that it throws exception that packet_id is missing before converter is invoked. I could try use PathVariable in POST method params and dont use ModelAtribute but i am not sure if it's good approach. 2 separate controllers is an option but it means i have to double every controller which is painfull.. I think i will have to use approach with custom ConversationalSessionAttributeStore or update every POST method so it take data from db and update specific fields

Comment: A `@PathVariable` is always required, else it shouldn't be part of that method. So you would have 2 methods 1 with and one without a `@PathVariable`. You don't need to do things with a `ConversationalSessionAttributeStore`, you just have to make sure your mappings are correct. A note on Spring Data JPA I would suggest using it, it makes your live a lot easier.

Comment: I dont get it... Can you show working example of controller where add, edit, and display page should work for packet object assuming i use Spring Data JPA so converters should works. How to mix PathVariable and ModelAttribute in POST method? Anyway thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @M. Deinium

This does work and whilst fresh I wanted to add additional enhancement required to make it work as required or as per last comment by jgr on edit display page and hope it makes sense

```
@Controller
public class PacketController {
    public static String BINDING_RESULT="org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.";
    private final PacketValidator PacketValidator;
    
    public PacketController(PacketValidator PacketValidator) {
        this.PacketValidator = PacketValidator;
    }
    @ModelAttribute
    public PacketDTO packet(@PathVariable(value = "id", required=false) Long id) {
         PacketDTO packetDTO = new PacketDTO();
         //if there is an id then connect and fill in DTO
         if (id != null) { 
           Packet packet = packetService.findById(id);
           //implement method to assign all objects to DTO
           packetDTP.assign(packet);
         }
         //either return  a new instance or one filled depending on if there was an id
        return  packetDTO;
    }

    //This would Hit above ModelAttribute but because there is no id it will assign a blank DTO
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String changePacketForm() {
        return "packets/packetSearch";
    }


    //This would be posting to change-step2
    @GetMapping("/change-step1/{id}")
    public String changePacketForm() {
        return "packets/packetStep1";
    }


    //If whilst in step 2 the user wants to change mind and go back it needs to post
    // to retain object
    @PostMapping("/change-step1/{id}")
    public String changePacketForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "packet") {
        return "packets/packetStep1";
    }

    //This would be getting form from packetStep1
    @PostMapping("/change-step2/{id}")
    public String editPacketForm() {
        //If in step 2 we wanted to get back to step 1 in the form there would be a button
        // within step2 to post back to step 1
        return "packets/packetStep2";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit-packet/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPacketForm() {
        return "packets/packetEdit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/edit-packet/{packet_id}")
    public String packetEditAction(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "packet") 
                                   Packet packet, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        PacketValidator.validate(packet,bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // There are issues if you are going to redirect back to get action:
            // you will need like sessionAttribute this 
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BINDING_RESULT+"packet", bindingResult);
            //Being stateless you must also pass back object
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("packet", packet);
            //Redirect back to where get was
            return  REDIRECT_URL+"/add";
    
            //Or if you are going to load page up here then you won't need any redirect attributes
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "packets/packetEdit";
            }
        }
                                   
     

        packetService.update(packet);
        return "redirect:/";
        
        
    }
}
```

Please also be aware with sessionAttribute a DTO or object is in session and therefore there is no need to have or collect existing form fields within the html pages used within any amount of given forms, if you do go down the route of stateless (above) then were ever there are secondary forms perhaps a confirmation page etc all existing fields submitted has to be made hidden input type fields within those forms. Otherwise if you go back it will reset data back to what ever top part does when it loads in DTO

Please also note if you are saving existing entries you will need typically two save actions

```
//For new entries
@GetMapping("/save")


//For existing entries
@GetMapping("/save/{id}")
```